# How to fix error "The page you selected contains a list that does not exist."

Tags: 2010, list, error

I've checked out the home page of a sub-site to my site collection and now it's broken with this error, and I don't know how to roll it back to the earlier version:

```
Error 
List does not exist.

The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 4a940289-85cf-44a9-ad8f-827770f88f76 

Date and Time: 7/17/2011 9:35:49 AM
```

Non-admin users can view the unbroken site just fine. Is there a way to roll the page/site back to the version that wasn't broken? I'm not sure how to discard the checkout.

Comment: Found a rather obscure way of getting to the broken site/page: http://www.codepoll.com/cp-Sharepoint/category/MS-SharePoint/post/sharepoint-error-The-page-you-selected-contains-a-list-that-does-not-exist-It-may-have-been-deleted-by-another-user.aspx. You put `?contents=1` on the URL to the broken site and load it. Then from there you can delete the list that's causing the issue and also discard the checkout. I wish there was an easier way to fix these things. Maybe there is and I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way to call the webpart maintenance page, here is a link with more url parameters. The post is about 2007, but also applies to 2010: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/url-parameters-for-sharepoint-2007/

Answer (score 2):

We get this error usually when there is mismatch in list id,
when we move from stage to prod.

If you have customized the lists new, edit or display page through designer you have to fix the URL.

Even the same case with the InfoPath, but usually when you move site from stage to prod you won't face any issue. I forgot the scenario but I fixed infopath issue like what is said in my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the page URL add `?Contents=1` , you'll get a webpart maintenance page, there close all the webparts. After that open them one by one and you'll come to know about the faulty webpart. In the end just remove or fix the faulty webpart. It always helped me to fix these kind of issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happened to us during a migration. The issue was in the Page Layout. It was using some SharePoint Controls that had a hard-coded List ID from the source site.

The solution was to edit the Page Layout manually and correct the List IDs to the equivalent List IDs in the destination site.

Answer (score 0):

Export the infopath form and edit manifest file, find the main data connection there.. change your new list ID's GUID and contenttype id
then again republish

Comment: OP never mentions using infopath. And the error message is a foundation error

Comment: Are you sure your answer is in the right question?