# Accessing a migrated list display form will return this error "The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. "

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-part, migration

I have migrated a SharePoint on-premises 2013 custom list to SharePoint online, and the on-prem list display form contains a **filter web part referencing another list**. now after the migration when I access the online list display form, I will get this error:-

[image]

after doing some reading, it seems the filter web part will reference the on-prem list ID which no more exits inside the SP online, so I will get this error. so I enter the web part maintenance page by adding `?content=1` to the URL, and I remove the filter web part, and now I only get the web part for the current list, as follow:-

[image]

but still when I access the display form I will get the same error.. any advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the list itself is broken as well.

If it is the default list web part, delete it from the Web Part Page Maintenance page and then try opening the list again.

See a similar post here: 
[How to fix error “The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-fix-error-the-page-you-selected-contains-a-list-that-does-not-exist)